# Reading Local JSON data

Tags: html, json, angular

So how to read the local JSON data if the structure is like this-
{
"employees":
[ "id":1,
"name":Mike,
"location":[
"first-address":India,
"Sec-address":Bangalore
]
]
}

how to access location using the angular Framework?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided much info in the question but Im guessing you've got a string and you want to convert it to JSON which you do with JSON.parse

```
const obj = JSON.parse('{ "employees": [ "id":1, "name":Mike, "location":[ "first-address":India, "Sec-address":Bangalore ] ] }')
```

Now you can access as follows:

```
console.log(obj.employees[0].id)
```

Or if not in string format:

```
const obj = { "employees": [ "id":1, "name":Mike, "location":[ "first-address":India, "Sec-address":Bangalore ] ] }

console.log(obj.employees[0].id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question needs more clarification, according to my understanding 
if you want to convert string format into JSON with `JSON.parse(object)` and store it in variable named obj 
and you can access **location** attribute by 
`console.log(obj.employees[0].location)`